# How to set default background on Skype?

Tags: macos, skype, macos-catalina

Is it possible to set a default background on Skype?

Ever since I added a few custom backgrounds using "Add image", whenever I restart Skype and take a call, the call initiates with a custom background and I have to go into the Audio & Video settings and reselect "None". Even when I do this, the next time I start Skype and take a call, it all starts over again. I would like to default Skype to always use the "None" background. Even when I delete all my saved custom backgrounds from settings, it always starts with the "Blur" option, which I don't want. It's bothersome to have to go into the settings and tinker with the background options every time I start Skype.

I'm using version 8.61.0.95 on MacOS Catalina 10.15.5.

Answer (score 1):

Click on your picture at the top left and go to settings, then to Audio & iVdeo.  Set the default background here